# Any recommender engine, technique for a "Suggested Topics" block?

Tags: cluster-analysis, recommendation-engine

I am planning to do a "Suggested Topics" block behind topics on my web forum and now I am looking for advice on this. Which recommender engine or techniques do I need to use for this task?

I understand that this is a problem of clustering but I am not worked with this area before.

Comment: Please do not cross-post duplicates: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/43950/924

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, instead of clustering you should just use an actual recommender system.

Or you just use *search*, such as Apache Lucenes "more like this" function.